# Android: Android kill tcpdump process

Tags: android, tcpdump

First sorry for my bad English.

I have developed an app in Android Studio. It call tcpdump (Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c tcpdump -s 0 -v -w /sdcard/capture.pcap");). Initially it works correctly. However, tcpdump process is killed abruptly. Would anyone tell me why?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It might tell you why on standard error:

```
final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(tcpdumpCommand);
final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
(new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      Log.d("tcpdump", "stderr: " + line);
    }
    Log.d("tcpdump", "end of stderr");
  }
}).start();
```

...and then look in logcat. Or try the same with `getOutputStream()` (for stdout) instead of `getErrorStream()`.

Also if tcpdump was successfully capturing traffic and then abruptly stopped, one possible reason is you've filled the SD card.